# Get other user's Outlook availability information

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, automation

I am writing an application that creates an overview of peoples Outlook calendars, i.e it will show the amount of unplanned time per week for the coming [n] weeks.

The basics are working, but there's one thing that I am having trouble with. Some users have shared their Outlook calendar in a way so that other users can only see availability information (the time and description of the appointments), but not any details.

I verified this by opening Outlook manually and opening a shared calendar; hovering the mouse over an appointment will show a popup with begin and end time, description and location, but double clicking it gives an error: "You are not authorized to display the calendar, do you want to ask [person] to share it?".

The relevant lines from my code are:

```
var outlook = new Application();
var mapiNamespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

var recipient = mapiNamespace.CreateRecipient("Scott");
recipient.Resolve();

var calendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
var calendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
```

Everything I now try to do with calendarItems will raise an exception. For instance, getting `Count` will raise a TargetInvocationException (*The client process failed*, but I'm not quite sure about the exact English translation). Calling `Sort("[Start]")` will raise a COMException with message *Unknown property: Start*. Both do work for fully shared calendars.

Now, for the overview, all I need is begin and end times, so I don't really want to ask everyone to change their sharing settings, especially when that shouldn't be necessary.

My questions are:

- Most important: Is there another way to get availability info that I'm overlooking?
- And related: Is Interop still the way to go these days, or are there alternatives? Maybe an Office365 webservice?

Comment: I've used [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220535(v=exchg.80).aspx) in the past to get this information in an organization that uses Office365. I will note though that the account you authenticate with still needs permissions to view the requested calendar information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `GetSharedDefaultFolder` and accessing the items in that folder, you can use `Recipient.FreeBusy` method.

Comment: Thanks. That sure is one of the strangest result values for a method I have ever seen.

Comment: Do you have any idea what value '5' in the result means? The enumeration only goes up to 4 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olbusystatus-enumeration-outlook

Comment: The same as "4" then. Well, OK then, I guess.

Comment: Hmmm.. Must be something different. Do you have access to the appointment that returns that value?

Comment: No, the owner is currently not available and it will take a couple of weeks before I see him. If I can find the time, I'll try some options in my own calendar. (it's a low priority project). Thanks for your help.